# Insert data into mysql database using C sharp Three Tier Architecture MVC ( MysqlParameter inserting null value )

Tags: c#, mysql, model-view-controller

Hello guys here i got `cities` table has 4 columns `cityId` is "AUTO_INCREMENT",`cityName`,`governate`,`conId` is a foreign key references to `countries`table

and they are stored procedure to insert data into this table using `last_insert_id()`

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addCity`(in  cityNamee varchar(45),bGovernate varchar(45),cconId int(5),out ccityId int(5))BEGIN insert into cities(`cityName`,`governate`,`conId`)values (@cityNamee,@bGovernate,@cconId);set @ccityId=last_insert_id();END
```

the sp was called from a business layer (controller) and  passing throw to model then execute the procedure here is the model to passing command of insert,update,delete

```
public void Transfare(string _chanPoro, MySqlParameter[] _dataContainer)
    {
        MySqlCommand transmeter = new MySqlCommand
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            CommandText = _chanPoro,
            Connection = dbcon
        };

        transmeter.Parameters.AddRange(_dataContainer);
        connect();
        transmeter.ExecuteNonQuery();
        disConnect();
    }
```

I've tried to insert data using `MySqlParameter`  but it always failed and give me an error

```
 public static void insertCity(string cityName, string governate, int countryId)
    {
        try
        {
                _socket = new _ctrlChannel();

                MySqlParameter[] zair = new MySqlParameter[4];


                zair[0] = new MySqlParameter("@cityNamee", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45)
                { Value = cityName, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                };

                zair[1] = new MySqlParameter("@bGovernate", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                { Value = governate, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                };

                zair[2] = new MySqlParameter("@cconId", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                { Value = countryId, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                };

                zair[3] = new MySqlParameter("@ccityId", MySqlDbType.Int32,5)
                {  Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                };

                _socket.connect();
                _socket.Transfare("addCity", zair);
                _socket.disConnect();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException we) { MessageBox.Show("error" + we); }
    }
```

> `cityName` was not found in the collection

and i try to use the traditional ways insert data with this method and the main trouble here is inserting null value  into database (not working)and that is not supported in table design

```
  public static void insertNewCity(string cityName, string governate, int countryId)
    {
        try
        {
            _socket = new _ctrlChannel();

            _ctrlChannel.InitializeDb();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = _ctrlChannel.dbcon;
            cmd.CommandText = "addCity";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityNamee", cityName);
            cmd.Parameters["@cityNamee"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bGovernate", governate);
            cmd.Parameters["@bGovernate"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cconId", countryId);
            cmd.Parameters["@cconId"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ccityId", MySqlDbType.Int32);
            cmd.Parameters["@ccityId"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            _socket.connect();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            _socket.disConnect();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException we) { MessageBox.Show("error" + we); }
    }
```

> Note : The procedure is full working when i tested it on server

That is all thank you a lot  ...

Comment: When you want to use a null for a parameter you must use DBNull.Value instead of null. Or you could set a default on the parameter in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have getter and setter to save a value from the view into the business layer then business layer deliver to `dataAccessLayer` to insert it to database

```
    string _cityName;
    string _governate;
    int _countryId;
    private string cityName { get; set; }
    private string governate { get; set; }
    private int countryId { get; set; }

    public void prepare()
    {
        _cityName = cityName;
        _governate = governate;
        _countryId = countryId;
    }
    public  void insertCity( string _cityName ,string _governate, int _countryId)
    {
        try
        {
                _socket = new _ctrlChannel();

                MySqlParameter[] zair = new MySqlParameter[4];


                zair[0] = new MySqlParameter("@cityNamee", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45)
                { Value = _cityName, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                };

                zair[1] = new MySqlParameter("@bGovernate", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                { Value = _governate, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                };

                zair[2] = new MySqlParameter("@cconId", MySqlDbType.VarChar)
                { Value = _countryId, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                };

                zair[3] = new MySqlParameter("@ccityId", MySqlDbType.Int32,5)
                {  Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,Value=DBNull.Value
                };

            _socket.connect();
            _socket.Transfare("addCity", zair);
            _socket.disConnect();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException we) { MessageBox.Show("error" + we); }
    }
```